# JQuery jScrollPane is not working. I am loading dynamic content in div

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I want to show scrollbar in `<DIV>`. I am loading content from AJAX in a `<DIV>`.

My code is

```
javasript-----

var settings = {
        showArrows: true
        };

   var pane = jQuery('.scroll-pane');

   pane.jScrollPane(settings);

   var api = pane.data('jsp');

    jQuery.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data : {action: "get_following_list"},
        type: 'POST',
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        success: function(response) { // on success.. mber ' + i++)

        jQuery(".followspan").html("FOLLOWING");
         if(togle == 'yes'){
            jQuery(".followers1").slideToggle("slow");
        }
        api.getContentPane().html(response);
        api.reinitialise();
        //jQuery(".scroll-pane").html(response);
     }
    });
```

Scoll is not working.

If any one know the solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

in the css of the .

Greetings.

Comment: I used this  .scroll-pane
   {
                                width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
   }

Comment: @vaibhavshahu Use .scroll-pane { width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow: scroll; }

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but overflow: scroll; is not working in my case